# Appending a % to values in a dropdown array

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have a drop down array and I'd like the % symbol to the options.  Not sure how to go about this though.  I'm using Cakephp.

So far I have (in the Controller):

```
            case "Quiz":
            $quiz = $this->CourseModules->FormTemplates->find('list')->where(['active'=>true,'type'=>'Quiz']);
            $passMark = [100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10,0]; //find a prettier way to do this
            $this->set('passMark',$passMark);

            $this->set('quiz',$quiz);
            break;
```

and in the .ctp I have:

```
            echo $this->Form->input('pass_mark',['label'=>'Pass Mark','options'=> $passMark,]);
```

But this isn't working...it's just showing the drop down with the figures.

Comment: Can you not just edit the array? `$passMark = ["100%", "90%", ...`

Comment: If you need the values to be numbers and only the display part to include the %, then `$passMark = [100 => '100%', 90 => '90%', ...`.

Comment: No this won't work.  I need the values of the ints within the array.

Comment: Excellent Greg.  That worked.  Thanks so much.  I also have another question about accessing a variable in a Controller from an unrelated Controller but I'll put that in another question.  Thanks heaps again.